# Sharepoint Unique Permission Subfolder broken

Tags: 2013, 2010, 2016, sharepoint-server, unique-permissions

I have library with the following tree structure.

> Library > Folder 1 > SubFolder A > Files

All folders and subfolders have unique permissions. All files have unique permissions. All folders and subfolders have the same groups as the library, but if I delete a specific group from the library, the group gets deleted from the folders, subfolders, and files. ¿How can I delete a group from the library, without deleting it from the files and folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard for SharePoint, if you remove the group from the library it is removed from everything below it.  You will need to change the group permissions at the library level and not remove the group.